# d3 parition layout messes up when changing value accessor

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to make a d3 partition layout behave like Mike's treemap example on:
[Treemap](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582).

I did following steps on the file:

- search-replace "treemap" with "partition"
- remove the .sticky call on treemap layout because partition doesn's
  support it
- fix the color scheme for leaf nodes -> always return color(d.name)
- always put text on node -> always return d.name in text attribute

Initially the partition renders fine.  But if you switch between value functions "size" and "count" using the input controls at the top right, there are data nodes that start shifting their level in the hierarchy!!!

Can anyone help explain me what the solution to this problem is?

To easily reproduce the problem, I've created a jsfiddle on:
[jsfiddle for partition](https://jsfiddle.net/rc6vx3te/)

```
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
    var value = this.value === "count"
        ? function() { return 1; }
        : function(d) { return d.size; };
    node
        .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .call(position);
});
```

Comment: You need to specify a key function (second argument to `.data()`) that tells D3 how to match data and nodes. Probably `function(d) { return d.name; }`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I've tried just that on [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rc6vx3te/3/).  Now the transition doesn't work, and there is a hole in the graph.  It is apparently all but trivial to substitute one hierarchical layout with another.

Comment: I may have found a solution.  Changing the key function to something smarter to avoid collisions on key names
`function(d) { return d.parent ? d.parent.name+"."+d.name : d.name;}`